# RSA - bitlength of p and q

Tags: math, rsa, public-key-encryption

I'm just trying to understand the key generation part of RSA, and more specifically, selecting the p and q primes. Given a target bit length for the modulus, n, what range I should be generating p and q in?

The modulus, n, is the product of p and q, where p and q are both prime numbers. I've read that p and q should be relatively close to each other, and somewhere around sqrt(n). If the target bit length is, for example, 32 bits (very small I realise), then does that follow that p and q should be a random prime of a maximum 16 bits?

Thanks for any clarification

Rob

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For a 32-bit modulus the question is a bit academic:  your primary aim in choosing `p` and `q` is to make the product hard to factorize, but finding the prime factorisation of a number smaller than `2^32` is so easy that there's little point worrying about the sizes of `p` and `q` in this case.  Note that the mathematics will work just fine so long as `p` and `q` are *distinct* primes.

For something more realistic, like a 1024-bit modulus, then yes, you're pretty safe choosing two 512-bit primes `p` and `q` at random:  that is, choose `p` and `q` uniformly from the set of all primes in the range `[2^511, 2^512]`.  There's a notion of '[strong primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_prime)', which are primes designed to avoid particular possible known attacks---for example, you'll see recommendations that `p` and `q` should be chosen so that `p-1` and `q-1` have large factors, to guard against easy factorizations using [Pollard's 'p-1' algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm).  However, these recommendations don't really apply to large moduli and state-of-the-art factorization algorithms ([GNFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve), [ECM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_method)).  There are other possible cases that in theory could give an easy factorization, but they're so unlikely to turn up in practice from random choices of `p` and `q` that they're not worth worrying about.

Summary: just choose two random primes with equal bitlength, and you're done.

A couple of additional comments and things to think about:

1. Of course, if you do choose two 512-bit primes, you'll end up with *either* a 1023-bit *or* a 1024-bit modulus;  that's probably not worth worrying about, but if you really cared about getting exactly a 1024-bit modulus you could either restrict the range of `p` and `q` further, say to `[1.5 * 2^511, 2^512]`, or just throw out any 1023-bit modulus and try again.
2. Don't deliberately choose `p` and `q` so that they're near each other:  if `p` and `q` are truly close to each other (e.g., less than `10^10` apart, say), then their product `pq` is easily factorized by [Fermat's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method).  But if you're choosing random primes `p` and `q` in the range `[2^511, 2^512]`, this isn't going to happen with any sort of realistic probability.
3. When choosing a prime at random, a tempting strategy is to pick a random (odd) integer in the range `[2^511, 2^512]` and then increment it until you find the first prime.  But note that that does *not* give a uniform choice amongst all primes:  primes occurring after a large gap would be more likely to come up than other primes.  A better strategy is just to keep picking random odd numbers and keep the first one that's a prime (or more likely, a strong probable prime to so many randomly-chosen bases that you can be sure in practice that it's prime).
4. Make sure you've got a really good cryptographic source of random numbers on hand for your prime number generation.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's very helpful. I've found it hard to find any common best-practices used, so I'll consider all those points.